# creating a list with separating by character in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm trying to make a list of the top 4 maximum values with data from other dictionaries, but the result i get keeps separating each term into individual characters. The full code is:

```
max_list = []    
MaxSimilarity = 0
for d in year:
    f = FavActorFunction(max_films[c], d)    
    if d != MaxGrossFinder(c):
        if year[d] == c:
            if f > MaxSimilarity:
                MaxSimilarity = f
                max = d
max_list.append(max)

MaxSimilarity2 = 0            
for d in year:
    g = FavActorFunction(max_films[c], d)    
    if d != MaxGrossFinder(c):
        if d != max:
            if year[d] == c:
                if g > MaxSimilarity2:
                    MaxSimilarity2 = g
                    max2 = d
max_list.append(max2)

MaxSimilarity3 = 0            
for d in year:
    h = FavActorFunction(max_films[c], d)    
    if d != MaxGrossFinder(c):
        if d != max and d != max2:
            if year[d] == c:
                if h > MaxSimilarity3:
                    MaxSimilarity3 = h
                    max3 = d
max_list.append(max3)


MaxSimilarity4 = 0            
for d in year:
    i = FavActorFunction(max_films[c], d)    
    if d != MaxGrossFinder(c):
        if d != max and d != max2 and d != max3:
            if year[d] == c:
                if i > MaxSimilarity4:
                    MaxSimilarity4 = i
                    max4 = d
max_list.append(max4)
print max_list
```

the result I get is ['3', '0', '0', 'T', 'r', 'a', 'n', 's', 'f', 'o', 'r', 'm', 'e', 'r', 's', 'S', 'p', 'i', 'd', 'e', 'r', '-', 'M', 'a', 'n', ' ', '3', '3', '0', '0']

how do I alter this code to get ['300', Transformers, etc.]

Comment: I don't know which language this is, but the append function seems to take a string, which is an array and connects the arrays.
Post the name of the language please :)

Comment: I searched all of your questoins, are those questions belong to your homework?

Comment: I don't see how this can be happening. Can you take your original code, try to remove as much as possible with it still showing the same problem, and then post a version that is small, exhibits your problem, and is complete ( I can run it)

Comment: [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) would like you to use snake_case variable names rather than CamelCase, please.

Comment: Oh, and don't use `max` as a variable name - you're shadowing the builtin function `max`. Whenever you do things like that, your code is liable to break in strange ways if/when you/others try to use the builtin in that location.

Comment: We miss the one critical information (in all this mess of useless lines). What is `year` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your function `FavActorFunction` is returning a list of characters rather than a list of words.

If you iterate over a string, rather than iterating over a *list* of strings, this can happen. For example, notice what happens when I convert a string to a list:

```
>>> print list("Hello, world")
print list("Hello, world")
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ',', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

And since you are just now learning, consider this advice: use descriptive variable names. Names like `d`, `c`, `h` and `g` make your code almost impossible to understand. Use variables like `actor`, `director`, etc. You don't win bonus points for being concise (unless you have a bad instructor).

Comment: If that was the case, he'd have a list of lists. But that doesn't appear to be the case. (Of course, it could be that copied the output here incorrectly)

Comment: @Bryan `d` is appended, not `h`, the result of `FavActorFunction`. So we need to know what is `year`. I completely agree about the variable names...

Comment: `year` seems to be a dictionary, with `d` holding its keys. the really hard thing to understand is what is claimed to be the "result". the posted code makes exactly **four** appends to `max_list`, but this apparently produces a list of **thirty** strings?! the only way i can see to produce that result is if `list.extend` was being used rather than `list.append`.